# Преобразование массива в объект

Tags: javascript

Исходный объект

```
  obj = { 
    login: 'my login',
    email: 'my email',
    name: 'my name'
  }
```

Надо получить массив из свойств этого объекта

```
[obj.login, obj.email, obj.name]
```

Проблема в том что список свойств заранее неизвестен.
Помогите, замучался уже (((

UPD: дико извиняюсь, я слепошарый )))
Действительно, достаточно сформировать новый массив со значениями, а не именами литералов исходного объекта. По сути результат не меняется.

Когда в коде пишем

```
[obj.login, obj.email, obj.name]
```

Когда генерируем динамически

```
['my login', 'my email', 'my name']
```

Comment: `obj.` должно быть вначале каждого свойства?

Comment: @Владислав да. новый массив используется как аргумент у функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
obj = {
  login: 'my login',
  email: 'my email',
  name: 'my name'
}

let arr = Object.keys(obj).map(i => `obj.${i}`);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: не, так я пробовал, в итоговом массиве ключи при этом варианте - это строки, а надо чтобы это были переменные. их значения используются потом.

Comment: @Alex они не могут не быть строками) Иначе, если вы и вручную запишете `console.log( [obj.login, obj.email, obj.name] )` — он выведет значения этих ключей, т.е. [ 'my login', 'my email',  'my name']. А для чего понадобилось выводить именно такой массив?

Comment: @optimus тогда как вы объясните вот это https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values - в 4 блоке кода первая переменная columns - это переменная, а не строка. вот мне динамически надо переменные подставить

Comment: и как понять кто там 4тый блок ?)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych посчитать ) вас ссылка на конкретный якорь приведет.

Comment: @Alex, то, что вы хотите сделать можно с помощью деструктуризации, но здесь ограничение - не работает с неопределённым количеством переменных

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко да, я уже понял. Ваш ответ принял, так как по факту он правильный. Обновил шапку.

Comment: @Alex, просто прописать `Object.values(obj)`

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко да, именно так )